# Toggle Resource Groups not working 100% of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I created something where only 1 resourceGroup can be expanded at a time. When another one is toggled open, the other one closes. However, this only works like 95% of the time. When I toggle them quickly, it might not work and two get opened. Can anyone figure out why and how to fix this?

```
$(document).on('click','.fc-icon-minus-square:not(.open_now)',function(e){
    if($('.fc-icon-minus-square:not(.open_now)').length > 1){
      $('.fc-icon-minus-square:not(.open_now)').addClass("open_now");
      $('.fc-icon-minus-square').click();
    }
    else{
  $('.fc-icon-minus-square').not(this).addClass("open_now");
  $('.fc-icon-minus-square').not(this).click();
  $(this).removeClass("open_now");
    $('.open_now').click();
$(this).addClass("open_now");
}
})
```

https://codepen.io/adam-silver/pen/rNWLvYv?editors=001

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to simplify the code and use an optional bit of CSS as well.

On-click:

- Remove all open_now classes (don't check if the clicked element has open_now)
- Add open_now class to the clicked element

Something like:

```
$('.fc-icon-minus-square').removeClass("open_now");
$(this).addClass("open_now");
```

And in the CSS, I'd go with (optional, if you don't want the opened to be clicked):

```
.open_now {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: The code gets stuck in an infinite loops and the added css is not being applied when I add it. Any way you can produce your solution from the following code? https://codepen.io/adam-silver/pen/rNWLvYv?editors=001

Comment: Get rid of $(this).removeClass("open_now") and remove open_now class for all them using  $('.fc-icon-minus-square').removeClass("open_now")  then $(this).addClass("open_now")

Comment: Try to make a stack snippet showing this infinite loop.